# Jenkins htmlpublisher issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After choosing "Add post build action" and selecting "Publish HTML Reports" the htmlpublisher plugin displays the table header fields (html directory to archive, index pages, report title, keep past html reports) but does not display the fields to enter the data. Directly beneath the table header fields the Add and Delete buttons are displayed. I'm hoping someone has seen this behavior before and found a fix.

I'm running Jenkins on ubuntu 12.04. Other than not being able to publish html reports Jenkins is working and building jobs from SVN. No errors are reported in the Jenkins log. I initially was running Jenkins 1.424 when I noticed the problem (new install, so html publisher never used before). So I updated Jenkins to version 1.474 but the problem continued. I have removed and re-installed Jenkins, same results.

Thank you for your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: I am noticing the same thing. When I click the "Add" button, nothing happens. I have attached an image which shows this section: http://i.imgur.com/RQ4sj.png

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this bug has been noted: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14491

And apparently: "Reverting to Jenkins 1.473 while keeping the plugin to 1.0 works."

Comment: I have confirmed that reverting to Jenkins 1.473 solves it. You can download it here http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/1.473/ and drop it in place of the current jenkins.war file. Then restart and the problem is solved. For the long-term it would be good to watch that bug report to find if it ever is resolved in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the plugin works...

you should create your html separately - let's say you created a folder named "MyReport" that contains a lot of html files in it, and the "index" html file is index.html.

on the "Publish Html Report" fields you will have to fill the following:

- html directory to archive = MyReport
- index pages = index.html
- report title = My Report Title

and then you will have a link for that report from Jenkins UI

Comment: The trouble is that there are no input boxes to enter data. Here is a screenshot of what I'm noticing: http://i.imgur.com/RQ4sj.png

Comment: press "Add" and then you will have the fields

Comment: Pressing "Add" does nothing. That's the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem. I had to save/apply the plugin first, then refresh, and then it became editable.